# how to clamp a float the "other way" in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

so i want to clamp the rotation in my 2d gameobject but the rotation float is when it reach 180
it change to -180, so when i clamp

```
mathf.clamp(rotation, -90, 90);
```

it is clamp so i cant rotate to the "right side",but when i do want so i cant rotate to the "left side" i cant.here is my code

```
mathf.clamp(rotation, 90, -90);
```

how can i make it so i cant rotate to the "left side"?(its platformer game fyi)

here some example [image]
that is 180/-180 degrees

[image]
this is 90 degree

[image]
and this is -90 degree

Comment: Can you give a few examples of `rotation`covering all 4 quadrants (positive and negative values) and the expected result.

Comment: Would something as simple as `mathf.clamp(rotation + 90, 0, 180) - 90` work?

Comment: We need numeric examples.

Comment: what is numeric example?